# How to assign variable to merged Pandas dataframe within function

Tags: pandas, outer-join, pass-by-value

I'd like the dataframe passed into this function to be modified.

```
def func(df):
    left_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
    right_df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=['C', 'D'])
    df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    print("df is now a merged dataframe!")

test = pd.DataFrame()
func(test)
```

However, since Python passes by value, the callee `func()` gets a copy of `df` which points to the original empty dataframe.  When it is assigned to the merged dataframe, it creates a new object returned by `pd.merge()` and points `df` to this new object.  However, `test` is unchanged and continues pointing to the original empty dataframe.

How can we merge inplace in `func()` so `test` is actually changed?  I'd like something like `pandas.DataFrame.update()`, but this only lets you do left joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, something like this?

```
def func(df):
    left_df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
    right_df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=['C', 'D'])
    df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    print("df is now a merged dataframe!")
    global test 
    test = df

test = pd.DataFrame()
func(test)
print(test)
```

Output:

```
df is now a merged dataframe!
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  5  6
1  3  4  7  8
```

Comment: This definitely works!  According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895768/python-pandas-dataframe-is-it-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference), using global variables can make it difficult to track where changes occurred, but this is the best solution I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

**Python does not pass by value!**
**NOTE:**  This is bad coding practice in general
*PROOF*

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

def func(df):
    df.loc[:] = df * 2

print(test)
func(test)
print(test)

   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4

   0  1
0  2  4
1  6  8
```

---

Your issue is that you are naming a local version of the name `df`.  You need to alter the dataframe *`inplace`* somehow.

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))

def func(df):
    df.loc[:, 'C'] = 9

print(test)
func(test)
print(test)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

   A  B  C
0  1  2  9
1  3  4  9
```