# Append DataFrame inside Function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a function `test` that takes a DataFrame and appends data to it. I want the global variable placed into the function to be changed. I have the script below:

```
import pandas as pd
global dff

def test(df):
    df = df.append({'asdf':1, 'sdf':2}, ignore_index=True)
    return(df)

dff = pd.DataFrame()
test(dff)
```

After this, `dff` remains empty; it was not edited. However, if you do this:

```
import pandas as pd

def test(df):
    df['asdf'] = [1,2,3]
    return(df)

dff = pd.DataFrame()
test(dff)
```

`dff` will have `[1,2,3]` under the column `'asfd'`. Notice that I didn't even have to declare the variable as `global`.

Why is this happening?

I actually would like to know, because the second I think I understand variable workspaces, I'm proven wrong and I'm getting sick and tired of constantly running into this BS*

I know the solution to the problem is:

```
import pandas as pd

def test(df):
    df = df.append({'asdf':1, 'sdf':2}, ignore_index=True)
    return(df)

dff = pd.DataFrame()
dff = test(dff)
```

but I'm really just trying to figure out why the initial method isn't working, especially in light of the second script I've shown.

*obviously it's not complete BS, but I can't understand it after 3 years of casual programming

Comment: avoid globals, they will hurt you sooner or later

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I'm sure they will. Which is why I like the second script much better. I just don't understand what makes the second script work and the first script not.

Comment: keyword 'global', actually )

Comment: the second script is inlining, also a doubtful choice as long as your function returns

Comment: You are using global wrong, they indicate when you are using something outside the current scope, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @will7200 So global is to elevate a variable in the local namespace, not to put a variable into all namespaces, yes?

Comment: @u2berggeist correct you can just define: dff = pd.DataFrame() without having to use global

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update:

I found a very nice talk at PyCon 2015 that explains what I'm attempting to explain below, but with diagrams that make it significantly clearer. I'll leave the explanation below to explain how the original 3 scripts work, but I'd suggest going to watch the video:

[Ned Batchelder - Facts and Myths about Python names and values - PyCon 2015](https://youtu.be/_AEJHKGk9ns)

---

So, I think I've figured out what is happening in the two scripts above. I'll trying a break it down. Feel free to correct me if need be.

Few rules:

1. Variables are names of links/pointers to an underlying object that actually holds the data. For example, street addresses. A street address is not a house; it simply points to a house. So the address (101 Streetway Rd.) is the pointer. In a GPS, you might have it labeled as "Home". The word "Home" would be the variable itself.
2. Functions work on objects, not variables or pointers. When you pass a variable to a function, you are actually passing the object, not the variable or pointer. Continuing the house example, if you want to add a deck to a house, you want to the decking contractors to work on the house, not the meta-physical address.
3. The `return` command in a function returns an pointer to an object. So this would be the address of the house, not the house or the name you might call your house.
4. `=` is a function meaning 'point to this object'. The variable in front of the `=` is the output, the variable to the right is the input. This would be the act of naming a house. So `Home = 101 Streetway Rd.` makes the variable `Home` point to the house on 101 Streetway Rd. Let's say you moved into your neighbors house, which is 102 Streetway Rd. This could be done by `Home = Neighbor's House`. Now, `Home` is now the name of the pointer 102 Streetway Rd.

Here on out, I'll use `--->` to mean "points to"

Before we get to the Scripts let's start with what we want. We want the object `objdff` pointed to by a varia

### Script 1:

(without the `global dff` as that doesn't do anything relevant)

> ```
> import pandas as pd
>
> def test(df):
>     df = df.append({'asdf':1, 'sdf':2}, ignore_index=True)
>     return(df)
>
> dff = pd.DataFrame()
> test(dff)
> ```

So let's walk through the function. Nothing interesting happens until we get to:

`dff = pd.DataFrame()`

Here, we have the varible `dff` being assigned to the object created by `pd.DataFrame`, which is an empty dataframe. We'll call this object `objdff`. So at the end of this line, we have `dff ---> objdff`.

Next line: `test(dff)`

Functions work on objects, so we're saying that we're going to run the function `test` on the object that `dff` points to, which is `objdff`. This brings us to the function itself.

`def test(df):`

Here, we have what is essentially an `=` function. The object passed to the test function `objdff` is pointed to by the function variable `df`. So now `df --->objdff` *and* `dff---> objdff`

Moving onto the next line: `df = df.append(...)`

Let's start with `df.append(...)`. The `.append(...)` is passed onto the `objdff`. This makes the object `objdff` run a function called 'append'. As pointed out by @Jai, the `.append(...)` method uses a `return` command to output an entirely new DataFrame that has the data appended to it. We'll call the new object `objdff_apnd`.

Now we can move onto the `df = ...` part. What we have now is essentially `df = objdff_apnd`. This is pretty simple now. The variable `df` now points to the object `objdff_apnd`.

At the end of this line we have `df ---> objdff_apnd` and `dff ---> objdff`. This is where the problem lies. The object we want (`objdff_apnd`) is not being pointed to by `dff`.

So at the end, the variable `dff` is still pointing to `objdff`, not to `objdff_apnd`. This brings us to Script 3 (see below).

### Script 2:

> ```
> import pandas as pd
>
> def test(df):
>     df['asdf'] = [1,2,3]
>     return(df)
>
> dff = pd.DataFrame()
> test(dff)
> ```

Just like Script 1, `dff ---> objdff`. During `test(dff)`, the function variable `df ---> objdff`. This is where things are different.

The operation (?) `df['asdf'] = [1,2,3]` again, is sent to the underlying object `objdff`. Last time, this resulted in a new object. This time however, the `['asdf']` operation directly edits the object `objdff`. So the object `objdff` has the extra 'asdf' column in it.

Therefore at the end we have `df ---> objdff` and `dff ---> objdff`. So they point to the same object, which means the variable `dff` points to the edited object.

Once we break outside of the function, variable `dff` still points to `objdff`, which has the new data in it. This gives us the desired result.

### Script 3:

> ```
> import pandas as pd
>
> def test(df):
>     df = df.append({'asdf':1, 'sdf':2}, ignore_index=True)
>     return(df)
>
> dff = pd.DataFrame()
> dff = test(dff)
> ```

This script is exactly identical to Script 1, except for the `dff = test(dff)`. We'll get to that in a second.

Continuing from the end of Script 1, we left off right as the function `test(dff)` was ending, and we have `dff ---> objdff` and `df ---> objdff_apnd`.

The function `test` has the `return` command, and so returns the object `objdff_apnd`. This turns the line `dff = test(dff)` into `dff = objdff_apnd`.

Therefore at the end, we have `dff ---> objdff_apnd`, which is exactly the result we want.

Answer (score 2):

- I think pandas data frame, list and dictionary all these data types are passed by reference to the function and hence, this behavior.
- In the first script you are appending which is being appended to a whole new object as `append` returns a new object and hence it did not fill the original dataframe.
- In the second script you are assigning a particular dataframe column to original dataframe object and hence it filled the original dataframe object with column because you are modifying the original object
- you can check out this answer: [python pandas dataframe, is it pass-by-value or pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895768/python-pandas-dataframe-is-it-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)
- Check this list example:

  ```
  def test1(a):
      a.append(1)

  def test2(a):
      a = [1, 2, 3]

  def test3(a):
      a[0] = 10

  aa = list()
  test1(aa)
  print(aa)

  aa = list()
  test2(aa)
  print(aa)

  aa = list([1])
  test3(aa)
  print(aa)
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  [1]
  []
  [10]
  ```
- Relate this above list example with the pandas dataframe example
- If you check the `append` function of Dataframe:
  `DataFrame.append(other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=None)[source]
  Append rows of other to the end of this frame, returning a new object. Columns not in this frame are added as new columns.`
- As you can see in the description that `append` returns a new object
- The way you are using `global` keyword is wrong... I think even if you do not have `global` in the first script, still it won't make any difference... I do not the details about the `global` keyword so I will not mention anything about it.. But I know how to use the keyword and that is definitely not the right way to use it