# Why does Python error log function result in no rows written?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a list of projects:

```
projects = pd.DataFrame([['Project 1', 'AAA'], ['Project 2', 'BBB']], columns=['project_name', 'code'])
```

I have an empty df to store errors:

```
error_log = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Project', 'Error'])
```

I have an error logging function that should write a row to the empty df:

```
def log_error(df, df_row, friendly_text, error):
    df = df.append({'Project':df_row['project_name'],
                    'Error': friendly_text + ' due to this error: ' + repr(error)},
                   ignore_index=True)
```

This line runs without error...

```
for index, row in projects.iterrows():
    log_error(error_log, row, 'The project was not created', 'Help')
```

...but no rows are written to `error_log` (i.e. `print(error_log)` returns nothing).

If I put the guts of the function directly into the for loop like this...

```
for index, row in projects.iterrows():
    error_log = error_log.append({'Project':row['project_name'],'Error': 'The project was not created due to this error: ' + 'help'},ignore_index=True)
```

...it successfully writes rows to `error_log`.

Why are rows not being written to the empty df when the appending occurs within a function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868186/append-dataframe-inside-function

Comment: The `.append()` method returns a new DataFrame. You either need to return it from your log function, or make `error_log` a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.append()` doesn't modify the dataframe in place, it creates a new df. You're assigning that to the local variable `df`, not `error_log`.

The function should return the new df, and you can reassign the variable.

```
def log_error(df, df_row, friendly_text, error):
    df = df.append({'Project':df_row['project_name'],
                    'Error': friendly_text + ' due to this error: ' + repr(error)},
                   ignore_index=True)
    return df

for index, row in projects.iterrows():
    error_log = log_error(error_log, row, 'The project was not created', 'Help')
```