# Unexpected transformation in pandas DataFrame while editing its copy

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame `df` with different types of columns, some values of `df` are NaN.

To test some assumption, I create copy of `df`, and transform copied df to (0, 1) with pandas.isnull():

```
df_copy = df
for column in df_copy:
    df_copy[column] = df_copy[column].isnull().astype(int)
```

but after that BOTH `df` and `df_copy` consist of 0 and 1.
Why this code transforms `df` to 0, 1 and is there way to prevent it?

Comment: `df_copy = df` **never creates a copy in Python.** This is quite important to understand, generally, so you really should read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent it declaring:

```
df_copy = df.copy()
```

This creates a new object. Prior to that you essentially had two pointers to the same object. You also might want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925257/5152563) and note that DataFrames are mutable.

Btw, you could obtain the desired result simply by:

```
df_copy = df.isnull().astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

even better memory-wise

```
for column in df:
    df[column + 'flag'] = df[column].isnull().astype(int)
```