# Pandas DataFrame as an Argument to a Function - Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, parameter-passing

Suppose a Pandas DataFrame is passed to a function as an argument. Then, does Python implicitly copy that DataFrame or is the actual DataFrame being passed in?

Hence, if I perform operations on the DataFrame within the function, will I be changing the original (because the references are still intact)?

I just want to know whether or not I should make a Deep Copy of my DataFrame before passing it into a function and operating on it.

Comment: I will always recommend using deep copy

Comment: pretty good answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895768/python-pandas-dataframe-is-it-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If a function parameter is a **mutable object** (e.g. a `DataFrame`), then any changes you make in the function will be applied to the object.

E.g.

```
In [200]: df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,3]})

In [201]: df
Out[201]:
   1
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [202]: def f(frame):
     ...:     frame['new'] = 'a'
     ...:

In [203]: f(df)

In [204]: df
Out[204]:
   1 new
0  1   a
1  2   a
2  3   a
```

See [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) article for a good explanation on how Python passes function parameters.

Comment: dataframes are *mutable*, not *immutable*

Comment: @PaulH maybe op said DataFrame is an example of *not* immutable (=mutable) objects

Comment: @ DavidJohns: the way that's written is very ambiguous e.g. *"If arg is not a bear (e.g. a a koala)*. Much clearer to say *If it's a mutable object..."*