# Preprocess huge data with a custom data generator function for keras

Tags: python, keras, large-data

Actually I'm building a keras model and I have a dataset in the msg format with over 10 million instances with 40 features which are all categorical. For the moment i'm using just a sample of it since reading all the dataset and encoding it is impossbile to fit into the memory. Here a part of the code i'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
from category_encoders import BinaryEncoder as be
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


def model():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=233, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='selu'))
   model.add(Dense(12, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
   model.compile(SGD(lr=0.008),loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
   return model

def addrDataLoading():

   data=pd.read_msgpack('datum.msg')
   data=data.dropna(subset=['s_address','d_address'])
   data=data.sample(300000) # taking a sample of all the dataset to make the    encoding possible
   y=data[['s_address','d_address']]
   x=data.drop(['s_address','d_address'],1)

   encX = be().fit(x, y)
   numeric_X= encX.transform(x)
   encY=be().fit(y,y)
   numeric_Y=encY.transform(y)
   scaler=StandardScaler()
   X_all=scaler.fit_transform(numeric_X)
   x_train=X_all[0:250000,:]
   y_train=numeric_Y.iloc[0:250000,:]
   x_val=X_all[250000:,:]    
   y_val=numeric_Y.iloc[250000:,:]

   return x_train,y_train,x_val,y_val 



x_train,y_train,x_val,y_val=addrDataLoading()

model.fit(x_train, y_train,validation_data=(x_val,y_val),nb_epoch=20, batch_size=200)
```

So my question is how to use a custom data generator function to read and process all the data I have and not just a sample, and then use fit_generator() function to train my model?

**EDIT**

This is a sample of the data:
[netData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xUwk.png)

I think that taking different samples from the data results in different encoding dimensions.

For this sample there's 16 different categories: 4 addresses (3 bit), 4 hostnames (3 bit ), 1 subnetmask (1 bit), 5 infrastructures (3 bit ), 1 accesszone(1 bit ), so the binary encoding will give us 11 bit and the new dimension of the data is 11 previously 5. So let's say for another sample in the `address` column we have 8 different categories this will give 4 bit in binary and we let the same number of categories in the other columns so the overall encoding will result in 12 dimensions. I believe that what's  causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Slightly slow solution (repeating the same actions)

#### Edit - fit BinatyEncoder before create generators

Drop NA first and work with clean data further to avoid reassignments of data frame.

```
data = pd.read_msgpack('datum.msg')
data.dropna(subset=['s_address','d_address']).to_msgpack('datum_clean.msg')
```

In this solution data_generator can process same data multiple times. If it's not critical, you can use this solution.

Define function which reads the data snd splits index to train and test. It won't consume a lot of memory.

```
import pandas as pd
from category_encoders import BinaryEncoder as be
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

def model():
   #some code defining the model


def train_test_index_split():
    # if there's enough memory to add one more column
    data = pd.read_msgpack('datum_cleaned.msg')
    train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(data.index) 
    return data, train_idx, test_idx


data, train_idx, test_idx = train_test_index_split()
```

Define and initialize data generator, both for train and validation

```
def data_generator(data, encX, encY,  bathc_size, n_steps, index):
    # EDIT: As the data was cleaned, you don't need dropna
    # data = data.dropna(subset=['s_address','d_address'])
    for i in range(n_steps):
        batch_idx = np.random.choice(index, batch_size)
        sample = data.loc[batch_idx]
        y = sample[['s_address', 'd_address']]
        x = sample.drop(['s_address', 'd_address'], 1)
        numeric_X = encX.transform(x)
        numeric_Y = encY.transform(y)
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        X_all = scaler.fit_transform(numeric_X)
        yield X_all, numeric_Y
```

**Edited part** now train binary encoders. You should sub-sample your data to create representative training set for encoders. I guess error with the shape of the data was caused by incorrecly trained `BinaryEncoder` (`Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have shape (233,) but got array with shape (234,)`):

```
def get_minimal_unique_frame(df):
    return (pd.Series([df[column].unique() for column in df], index=df.columns)  
           .apply(pd.Series)  # tranform list on unique values to pd.Series
           .T  # transope frame: columns is columns again
           .fillna(method='ffill'))  # fill NaNs with last value

x = get_minimal_unique_frame(data.drop(['s_address', 'd_address'], 1))
y = get_minimal_unique_frame(data[['s_address', 'd_address']])
```

**NB**: I never used category_encoders and have incompatible system configuration, so can't install and check it. So, former code can evoke problems. In that case, I guess, you should compare length of `x` and `y` data frames and make it the same, and probaly change an index of data frames.

```
encX = be().fit(x, y)
encY = be().fit(y, y)
batch_size = 200
train_steps = 100000  
val_steps = 5000

train_gen = data_generator(data, encX, encY, batch_size, train_steps, train_idx)
test_gen = data_generator(data, encX, encY, batch_size, test_steps, test_idx)
```

**Edit** Please provide an exapmple of `x_sample`, run `train_gen` and save output, and post `x_samples`, `y_smaples`:

```
x_samples = []
y_samples = []
for i in range(10):
    x_sample, y_sample = next(train_gen)
    x_samples.append(x_sample)
    y_samples.append(y_sample)
```

**Note**: data generator won't stop itself. But itt will be stopped after `train_steps` by `fit_generator` method.

Fit model with generators:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_steps, epochs=1,
                    validation_data=test_gen, validation_steps=val_steps)
```

As far as I know, `python` does not copy pandas dataframes if you won't do it explicitply with `copy()` or so. Because of it, both generators use the same object. But if you use Jupyter Notebook, data leaks/uncollected carbage may occur, and a memory troubles comes with them.

#### More efficient solution - scketch

Clean your data

```
data = pd.read_msgpack('datum.msg')
data.dropna(subset=['s_address','d_address']).to_msgpack('datum_clean.msg')
```

Create train/test split, preprocess it and store as numpy array, if you have enough disk space.

```
data, train_idx, test_idx = train_test_index_split()

def data_preprocessor(data, path, index):
    # data = data.dropna(subset=['s_address','d_address'])
    sample = data.loc[batch_idx]
    y = sample[['s_address', 'd_address']]
    x = sample.drop(['s_address', 'd_address'], 1)
    encX = be().fit(x, y)
    numeric_X = encX.transform(x)
    encY = be().fit(y, y)
    numeric_Y = encY.transform(y)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_all = scaler.fit_transform(numeric_X)
    np.save(path + '_X', X_all)
    np.save(path + '_y', numeric_Y)

data_preprocessor(data, 'train', train_idx)
data_preprocessor(data, 'test', test_idx)
```

Delete unnecessary data:

```
del data
```

Load your files and use following generator:

```
train_X = np.load('train_X.npy')
train_y = np.load('train_y.npy')

test_X = np.load('test_X.npy')
test_y = np.load('test_y.npy')

def data_generator(X, y, batch_size, n_steps):
    idxs = np.arange(len(X))
    np.random.shuffle(idxs)
    ptr = 0

    for _ in range(n_steps):
        batch_idx = idxs[ptr:ptr+batch_size]
        x_sample = X[batch_idx]
        y_sample = y[batch_idx]
        ptr += batch_size
        if ptr > len(X):
            ptr = 0
        yield x_sapmple, y_sample
```

Prepare generators:

```
train_gen = data_generator(train_X, train_y, batch_size, train_steps)
test_gen = data_generator(test_X, test_y, batch_size, test_steps)
```

And fit the model finaly. Hope one of this solutions will help. At least if python does pass arrays and data frames buy reference, not by value. [Stackoverflow answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895768/python-pandas-dataframe-is-it-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference).

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't solve my problem. The  `addrDataLoading()` function use  `data = data.sample(300000)`  and there's always the encoding of that huge data in which is the core of the problem.

Comment: I've got it, will fix my answer in a hour

Comment: I think there's one more bug in my solution, don't re-assign `data`, because it will be copied in this case.

Comment: 1st method seems to be working but I have this problem `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_9_input to have shape (233,) but got array with shape (234,)`. I think parameters of `model()` should be adapted. I've edited the above code to include the `model()` function code.

Comment: @mEdiHan looks like your model gets more columns that it expects. If you use my code now, you should check that generator returns x_sample with correct shape (233,) (not it is wrong, yep). Probably there's some additional column was added to your data and was'nt removed from it. With no data I can't figure out whrere is the problem. If you post `print` of x_sample from that code and how it was in your original code, I can answer more accurately. Now I think that some index column remained in your data (probably).

Comment: @Stepanov I've added a small sample of the data

Comment: @mEdiHan There's not enough data. If you post printed `x_sample` from my answer and `x_train` from you original (without such `ValueError`) on https://pastebin.com/ or so and post a link, it will help. Or you can just change `model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=233, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='selu'))` to    `model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=234, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='selu'))`. But beware of data leaks - i.e index, date, etc.

Comment: The second solution where there's ``x_train` doesn't work for me. The first one works and gives the error.

Comment: @mEdiHan I just added hypothesis (*just hypothesis*) why this code fails. Please check it and provide some requested data (code at the end of the answer), if the fix won't help.