# Passing multiple columns to a function as argument and getting a new column from the function for the dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, function, arguments

I'd like to create a new column by the return values of a function that requires two columns as arguments.

Here is my dataframe(df). the data frame has multi-column index

| Time | Temp | Press |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sec | K | kPa |
| 0.00 | 300 | 101 |
| .... | .... | .... |
| 4.00 | 380 | 180 |

And I have a function returning a new value from the Temp and Press

```
def density(Temp, Press)
    ....
    return rho
```

With this function, I'd like to create a new column  as below

| Time | Temp | Press | Density |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sec | K | kPa | kg/m3 |
| 0.00 | 300 | 101 | 1000 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| 4.00 | 380 | 180 | 1004 |

From my own searching, it seems that I need to use 'apply'.

So I tried some codes like

```
df['Density', 'kg/m3'] = df['Density', 'kg/m3'].apply(density, args=(df['Temp', 'K'], df['Press','kPa']))
```

And I got the error message

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

From a [QnA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895768/python-pandas-dataframe-is-it-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference), I guess the function definition shall be modified to have dataframe type as arguments. But I'm stuck here.

It would be solved if I use another method like for-iteration. But I expect that there is a faster and neat expression for this problem.

Is there a solution for this?

I appreciate it in advance. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works for a long time and yields the result anyway

```
df['Density', 'kg/m3'] = df.apply(lambda x:density(x['Temp', 'K'], x['Press','kPa']), axis=1)
```

The 'data' is large(ASCII, 22 Mb) but I wonder if there is a way to accelerate the calculation.