# function to drop outliers

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I created a function to drop my outliers. Here is the function

```
def dropping_outliers(train, condition):
    drop_index = train[condition].index
    #print(drop_index)
    train = train.drop(drop_index,axis = 0)
```

and when I do

```
dropping_outliers(train, ((train.SalePrice<100000)  & (train.LotFrontage>150)))
```

Nothing is being dropped.However when I manually execute the function. i.e get the index in the dataframe for this condition, I do get a valid index (943) and when I do

```
train = train.drop([943],axis = 0)
```

Then the row I want is being dropped correctly. I don't understand why the function wouldn't work as its supposed to be doing exactly what I am doing manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of `dropping_outliers`, it's assigning the result of `drop` to a local variable, not altering the dataframe passed in. Try this instead:

```
def dropping_outliers(train, condition):
    drop_index = train[condition].index
    #print(drop_index)
    return train.drop(drop_index,axis = 0)
```

Then do the assignment when you call the function.

```
train = dropping_outliers(train, ((train.SalePrice<100000)  & (train.LotFrontage>150)))
```

Also see [python pandas dataframe, is it pass-by-value or pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38895768/1288).