# how to aggregate multiple tasks into a single python function?

Tags: python, dataframe, function

I'm working on a dataframe that i have been able to clean by running the following codes in separate cells in jupyter notebook.  However, I need to run these same tasks on several dataframes that are organized exactly the same.  How can i write a function that can execute the tasks 2 through 4 below?

For reference, the date I'm working with is located [here](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

```
[1]: df1 = pd.read_csv('202110-divvy-tripdata.csv')

[2]: df1.drop(columns=['start_station_name','start_station_id','end_station_name','end_station_id','start_lat','start_lng','end_lat','end_lng'],inplace=True)

[3]: df1['ride_length'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.ended_at) - pd.to_datetime(df1.started_at)

[4]: df1['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.started_at).dt.day_name()
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? To start, define a function that takes a dataframe as an input, does the things, and returns the new dataframe as an output. What specifically is tripping you up?

Comment: You can define a function directly in jupyter notebook just like you can do in regular python script. Just define the function in a cell and run the cell once. The function will remain defined as long as you don't restart the kernel or clear notebook state.

Comment: You could create a list containing the entries which are csv files' filenames, then write a simple for loop that calls the generator which in turn is the function and pass the filename as the parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function in a cell in `Jupyter`, run this cell and then call the function:

```py
def process_df(df):
    df['ride_length'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ended_at) - pd.to_datetime(df.started_at)
    df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df.started_at).dt.day_name()
```

Call the function with each `DataFrame`:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')

process_df(df1)
process_df(df2)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895768/python-pandas-dataframe-is-it-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference), both `DataFrame`s will be altered in place and there's no need to return a new object from the function.